# What is the best way to split a transport stream file?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a .ts file (Download files here: http://dropcanvas.com/2gmsg/1).

I want to split this video while I expect ALL other properties remain same including pts time.

Here is what I try to achieve this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 0.000 -i sample.ts -y -c copy -t 3 splitted.ts
```

Expected start time: 94678.950389 
New start time: 1.402367

I expect the above command should only take first 3 seconds of the .ts file and all other stuff to stay same. I've seen copyts and copytb options from the documentation but I wasn't able to use them.

So how do I do this?

Thank you

Here are the logs for copyts. It creates a 0 byte splitted.ts file:

```
ffmpeg -ss 0:00:00 -i sample.ts -to 00:00:03 -y -c copy -copyts splitted.ts
ffmpeg version 3.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.0 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-libfreetype --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-ffplay --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libopus --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[NULL @ 0x7fafac02fc00] start time for stream 2 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
Input #0, mpegts, from 'sample.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:10.07, start: 94678.950389, bitrate: 934 kb/s
  Program 1
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 854x480 [SAR 1280:1281 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 140 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x102]: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
Output #0, mpegts, to 'splitted.ts':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 854x480 [SAR 1280:1281 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, 140 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
```

Comment: Run it with copyts and paste the full console output of that command here.

Comment: Hi @Mulvya , I've added console output. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
ffmpeg -seek_timestamp 1 -ss 94678.950389 -i sample.ts -y -c copy -copyts -to 94681.950389 -muxdelay 0 splitted.ts
```

---

Your original command can work if you use the frames flag.

```
ffmpeg -ss 0.000 -i sample.ts -y -c copy -copyts -muxdelay 0 -vframes 90 splitted.ts
```

Where `90` represents amount of frames in `t` seconds.

Comment: In order to get current start time I will need to do another process on the segment which I'd like to avoid. You say my original command should also work but you also saw that it doesn't work, right? So does that mean a bug in ffmpeg you think? I'm trying to send a post to user email list but they don't approve and I don't have a clue why.

Comment: And ffmpeg adds these metadata: `Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg` How do I avoid it?

Comment: It looks like a bug in that `copyts` bypasses a function which resets input timestamps and the `t` uses the reset timestamps to determine exit point. See edited command. Will check into the metadata.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Mulvya, you've been really helpful. But there is another issue with the copy process. As you can see there is also a 'data' stream inside the stream but it's not copied. I'm using these segments in a HLS stream and I think because of the missing stream, player expects discontinuity tag before using it. Is there a way to get that stream too into the splitted segment? Thank you again!